# Cassette HG 51, which chain?

Tags: chain, cassette

I need to replace my cassette (Shimano HG30 8speed 11-32) and chain (KMC Z7) that is currently on my bike (pinnacle Aura), however these parts are now discontiuned and I need to find the replacments. I have been recommended the HG51 cassette but don't know which chain to get.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Any 8-speed chain should work. If you want to be absolutely sure, get one made by the same company that made the cassette. I believe Shimano still makes several 8-speed chains.

Comment: I used to use Shimano IG-51 with HG cassettes. As pointed, any 8speed chain work. Nowadays, KMC has having the best cost-benefit for me, specially considering its Power Link (makes life MUCH easier, I take the chain out of the bike for cleaning)

Comment: I once had a compatibility problem with a Surly fixie cog and a KMC chain. Theoretically, they should have meshed perfectly, but they didn't, and I have no idea which one was at fault. So that's the only reason I recommend getting the same brand for the chain and the cogs.

Comment: I ride fixie, and my cog is thicker than mtb so that it won't fit an 8 speed chain (these were named "narrow" some time ago...). I have to use a common BMX chain. Was this your case?

Comment: I'd have to go home and check, but I'm pretty sure my bike has an HG51, and I'm using an SRAM 8-speed chain.  Have had no problems.

Comment: I was using a single-speed BMX chain. So like I said, it should have fit. I realize that this sort of problem is pretty rare. (Also, now that I think back, it wasn't a KMC chain, it was something else.)

Comment: I checked and what I've been using is an HG50 cassette with SRAM PC58 and PC68 chains.  No problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have just purchased Shimano HG51 (11 - 30 tooth) casette and HG50 chain... I haven't fitted them yet but I have been advised they are compatible... see original post here.

[Difference between Shimano HG51 8-Speed Cassette and Shimano HG50 8-Speed Cassette](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8378/difference-between-shimano-hg51-8-speed-cassette-and-shimano-hg50-8-speed-casset)

Answer (score 1):

Shimano HG-XX cassettes are definitely not discontinued; just the numbers have changed. HG-30 became HG-40, and now HG-50.  You can find an 8 speed HG50 cassette in the gearing ranges from 11-28T to 11-34T ("Mega Range"). You can also replace with a non-Shimano cassette, which is compatible with the HUB. For instance SRAM PG-850 and others.

The cheap KMC 6-8 speed chains are everywhere. Maybe not exactly the "Z7", but some other number like "Z51".

Comment: I've had no luck with KMC chains, and would not consider them in the future.  One lasted three weeks before throwing a side plate.  Chain is like brake pads and tyres, not a place to save money.

Comment: @Criggie Indeed, KMC chains are the bottom-of-the-line cheapest stuff.